# How to make a dynamic component that update itself

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a component that receive by props a component that will be rendered. But this component can be updated and changed by itself. So, when I change in the first time, the component really works, but crash the Vue instance and the second component not work by itself.

I'm letting down a URL to Playground of my code.

[Playground Link](https://encurtador.com.br/mpDP3)

MAIN Component

```html
<script setup>
import { ref,shallowRef } from 'vue'
import Component1 from './Component1.vue';

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
const renderComponent = shallowRef(Component1)
const updateComponent = (component)=>{
renderComponent.value=component
}

</script>

<template>
 <component :is="renderComponent" @updateComponent="updateComponent"></component>
</template>
```

Component 1

```html
<script setup>
import Component2 from './Component2.vue';
const emit=defineEmits(["updateComponent"])
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Hello, I'm component 1
  </div>
  <button @click="emit('updateComponent',Component2)"> 
  click here to change component</button>
</template>
```

Component 2

```html
<script setup>
import Component1 from './Component1.vue';
const emit=defineEmits(["updateComponent"])
</script>

<template>
  <div>
     Hello, I'm component 2
  </div>
  <button @click="emit('updateComponent',Component1)"> 
  click here to change component</button>
</template>
```

I tried to use "ref", "shallowRef", "markRaw". But nothing works.
Also I tried to import all components into main, and nothing works to.

Comment: Why do you have the need to replace the current component with another? Couldn't you simply use [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) and simply link to the page where the other component is displayed?

Comment: do you need SSR?

Comment: @PeterPointer the motive for Vue Router is navigation, which this probably isn't a case for.   Dynamic components are just fine for complex conditional rendering that isn't meant to be route based.  They exist for a reason after all.

Comment: @yoduh Well the question was if they need a dynamic component in this case, because the question doesn't make the motivation for this clear. Why work on the XY problem when you can also just not. Sharing any console errors would also be helpful if they say it crashes the Vue instance.

Comment: So, I need to replace current component because this component is a Popup in Leaflet map. However Leaflet popup dont accept vue components only HTML content. Therefore, I made a Vue Instance just to handle popups and replace its content.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be for the child components to emit the string name of the dynamic component.  The parent will import all possible components and set the correct component based on the emitted string.

[Playground link](https://play.vuejs.org/#__SSR__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)

**App.vue**

```js
<script setup>
import { shallowRef } from 'vue'
import Component1 from './Component1.vue';
import Component2 from './Component2.vue';

// array to hold add as many as needed
const dynamicComponents = [Component1, Component2]

const renderComponent = shallowRef(Component1)
const updateComponent = (component) =>{
  renderComponent.value = dynamicComponents.find(c => c.__name === component)
}
</script>

<template>
 <component :is="renderComponent" @updateComponent="updateComponent"></component>
</template>
```

**Component1.vue (*Component2 being basically the same*):**

```js
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(["updateComponent"])
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Hello, I'm component 1
  </div>
  <button @click="emit('updateComponent', 'Component2')"> 
  click here to change component</button>
</template>
```

Comment: That's a well alternative. But I was tring not import all component that will be renderized, because the main component will be a popup handler and will display many diferents components. However, I like this solution, maybe I replace the 'find' iteration by a object Literal.